# Duplicate value from multiple database

Tags: multiple-databases

I want to make a list of all duplicate values for column ID from 4 databases in the same table A.

For Instance
DB1 has TableA and Column ID
DB2 has TableA and Column ID
DB3 has TableA and Column ID
DB4 has TableA and Column ID

and I want to find duplicate Column ID value from all tables.
I cant think of any idea to code it, can someone throw some light ?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is simply, create a new table or a temp table, and then simply insert all your data from all 4 database into one table or temp table. This will help not chew too much querying resources.

Once done, simply use a query like this:

Supposed you declared temp table as: TempDuplicateTable

```
Select a.ColumnID, b.duplicates
From TempDuplicateTable a
join (
    select distinct(ColumnID), count(*) as duplicates
    from TempDuplicateTable 
    group by ColumnID
    having count(*) > 1
) b on a.ColumnID= b.ColumnID
```

Comment: currently I have 4 DB but soon it would be 40, your solution will be too much of manual process for large number of DB

Comment: Actually, if data is periodically placed in one table, the computation will be faster, this will be superior then having joins of 40 different databases in one query.
Hence simply automate a process to insert data into this one table.